# Counterpart of .NETs NetworkStream / SslStream in Delphi 7

Tags: .net, delphi, sockets, ssl, networkstream

I have written a secure TCP server in .NET. This was basically as simple as creating a TcpListener instance and wrapping the connected client's NetworkStreams with SslStreams.

Now I need to access this TCP server with Delphi 7 (alternatively: Delphi 2007).

I haven't found anything in the help, and a Google search shows up lots of complex commercial packages. Is there a simpler solution, or something integrated in Delphi I have overlooked?

If not, are there any simple free or commercial packages I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download), which is also a free solution which is easy to use.  It differs from Indy in that it doesn't use components, but rather simple blocking functions.  For the SSL support, Synapse supports the use of [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) via a simple to use wrapper.

Comment: Great. Exactly what I've looked for :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx). It's free. A version of it even came with Delphi 7, although I recommend you go download a more recent version. (The Web page I linked calls it Indy.Sockets to differentiate it from some of the other projects Indy has branched out into.)

Answer (score 1):

See [OpenSSL with Delphi](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_5010.asp?SK=). It mentions Indy and [DelphiWebStart](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiwebstart/).

Answer (score 0):

[ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/eng/products/ics.html), the Internet Component Suite. It's free.

Answer (score -1):

None of Indy / ICS / Synapse have built-in SSL. They plug third-party modules, such as OpenSSL or our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbbdev/delphi-ssl.php) product.